# React router: Create 'Link to' paths from objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have an index of images and titles I am pulling in from the Dropbox api. These (when clicked) already create and mount new components. I'm trying to integrate react-router into this project but am struggling to generate *Link to=* paths using the array I have already created.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

//titles variable created via api
var titles=["title one","title two","title three",...]


class Index extends React.Component{

    render(){
        if(!this.props.imageSource.length)
            return null;
            let titles = this.props.imageTitles.map((el, i) => <p>{el}</p>)
            let images = this.props.imageSource.map((el, i) =>

                <div className="imageContainer">
                  <img key={i} className='indexImages' src={el} onClick = {this.props.indexTitleClick.bind(this,titles[i])}/>
                  <Link to={titles[i]} className="imageTitle" onClick = {this.props.indexTitleClick.bind(this,titles[i])}>{titles[i]}</Link>
                </div>
            )



        return (
            <div className="indexWrapper">
                {images}
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to use the same method as I have for generating the imageTitles, but the href is simply "/" when rendered. Is it possible to dynamically generate paths in this way?

p.s. I've tried to keep the code concise here but happy to add in more info if needed.

Comment: what does `this.props.imageTitles` looks like?

Comment: `titles[i]` should give you `<p>title one</p>` and I believe this is not a valid `to` prop. change variable names titles and titleshml or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure you are aware of that but you overriding `titles`.

```
var titles=["title one","title two","title three",...] // from outside your component
let titles = this.props.imageTitles.map((el, i) => <p>{el}</p>) // inside render
```

Then, you are trying to link to the members of `titles` array but it holds members in this format:

```
<p>{el}</p>
```

Comment: Nice spot, OP If you used a const instead of the var you would of trapped this error quickly

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a Root class where you will declare some paths like the below example

```
 <Router history={browserHistory} >               
    <Root path="/:pathVariable" component={ComponentClass}/>           
 </Router>
```

and then with browserHistory.push("/path") you will navigate to http://host:port/path